# Mathematica 12.3 won't launch. Freezes on 'opening welcome screen' and turns off

Tags: front-end, kernel

Mathematica 12.3 won't launch. Freezes on 'opening welcome screen' and turns off.

Mathematica Kernel works properly.

Specifications:
Version: 12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 24, 2021)
OperatingSystem: Windows 10 Home 20H2
ProcessorType: x86-64
Paclets: PacletManager Version 5.0.0

Mathematica worked correctly until two weeks ago. I don't think I installed any software that might obscure its functioning.

I tried deleting paclets, full reinstall (including and not including steps shown in: https://support.wolfram.com/12473)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you contacted Wolfram Support about this issue?

Comment: Yes, so far unsuccessful:
They told me to 
1) Run this command in Kernel: SystemInformation[]  -- which I did.
2) Follow these steps
https://support.wolfram.com/12473
which didn't work.
3) Then to follow these steps:
https://support.wolfram.com/42872
which obviously I can't do

Comment: I have experienced the same problem and found that deleting directories as described [support.wolfram.com/12464](https://support.wolfram.com/12464) worked.for me.

Comment: I did that as well (the 12464) -- did not work.
Then I resintalled -- did not work.
After that I removed all wolfram-related files from my system (including cache files for Wolfram Script) -- did not work
After this removing I reinstalled again -- did not work

Comment: Updating to Windows 11 helped and front end works now.
I was also able to create .dmp files -- perhaps wolfram support will be able to pinpoint the problem. If so, I will comment here.